# Thesis: a downvote should never fail a first post audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Over and over, we read that our votes are our own. Yet, I've flunked two audits in first posts in the last 24 hours because I downvoted a post. There are nominal standards for closing or deleting, so, by all means, flunk me if I ask to VTC against the tide. But if I want to vote down any answer that starts out by gassing off about whether something is 'pythonic' or some other subjective nonsense, I think that's my privilege, as much in first post as in anywhere else. Nowhere else do we demand that voting honk with the other geese in the flock, why here?

Comment: Do what I do: if the score is 0, open it in a new tab.  If it's deleted, flag.  If its score is >0, upvote.  That's the only way to avoid being constantly banned.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Voting as a review action is, and always has been, a terrible idea. I sincerely regret adding it to this queue, and solemnly pledge to do all that I can to see it removed.

Until then, I recommend either flagging or editing as your review options when in First Posts or Late Answers. They're both really useful, and it's generally pretty obvious when they should be used.

Comment: Thank you. How about also getting the diamonds to stop looking at NotAnAnswer flags, so they just push things into the queue? It's disconcerting to get a 'review declined flag' when I'm just trying to get a dud where my peers can look at it.

Comment: Eh; you've had one declined flag in many months (compared to several disputed flags which went through review), and honestly I tend to agree with the moderators' decision there - it wasn't a great answer, but it did attempt to provide a solution. Realistically, we should probably be declining flags from review as well if they don't get any support - which I expect would tend to soften folks impression of the mods a bit.

Comment: You're not talking about removing the *ability* to vote from the queue right? Just the bit about throwing an audit right? Right?

Comment: I'm not claiming that I was _right_. Just that I take a lot more care when I'm bugging a person than when I'm nominating for review by my fellow peons, and this particular flag is amphibious this way.

Comment: Consider that you're "bugging" at minimum two and potentially many more people when your flag *does* end up in review. Granted, they're probably not as busy - but still, if everyone did that...

Comment: @bmargulies there's a feature request at MSE: [Hide “not an answer” and “very low quality” flags in the moderator flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/165773)

Comment: Is this ever going to happen?