# Allow voting from review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, voting

I was thinking this might have been asked already, but I couldn't find anything.

Here is the scenario:

I see a crap question / Answer from the review queues with an upvote. I want to make sure it gets closed/deleted. From what I know, regardless of all the delete votes upvoted stuff won't be deleted.

(I've seen comments like, *"for those in review queue, this needs more downvotes to actually get deleted"* and it is true from my observation)

Now, I'd like to vote on a post from the review queue itself without having to open a new tab and going to the post.

I can not think of a way in which this might be misused, since one can always go to the post and vote. is there any?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211641/up-down-voting-on-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277348/2581872

Comment: @hichris123 just to clarify, this request is not asking to add voting as a *review action* in reviews, it is just asking to simply add it there so that I don't have to open the post in a new tab just for voting purpose.

Comment: I think I know a way it can be misused: Going to the post and vote is work. Just having the buttons right there means a bad question gets many more downvotes than without. But my impression is that bad question get already enough downvotes as it is and for those struggling to survive and improve their question this would probably be deadly. As it is it's much better balanced. The purpose of the review queue may just not be to vote on the question's usefulness but whether it should be deleted or not. I mean it would be just unfair over all the questions that do not appear in any queue.

Comment: @Trilarion: I see it a bit differently. When reviewing [late answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) I often see answers to old questions which ask for an off-site resource. According to discussions here on Meta, I understood that the correct action is to downvote the question in this case. Maybe TJ had a similar case in mind when posting his question.

Comment: @honk Asking for an off-site resource should be a reason to vote for deletion instead of downvoting, shouldn't it? These are not even an attempt to answer. What discussions on Meta are advicing to downvote instead?

Comment: @Trilarion: The problem with old off-topic questions is that they won't be deleted as long as they have a positive vote count. As far as I understood, flagging for deletion will only have an effect, if the vote count is drained to zero or even below. Therefore, flagging for deletion alone won't do the trick. Please let me know if I got that wrong.

Comment: @honk I don't know but in case it's like this you're right and it's an argument for this proposal.

Answer (score 8):

The triage queue doesn't allow downvoting (or upvoting except when a question graduates from triage).  Yet nearly all of the questions I triaged as unsalvageable deserved downvotes.  As the queue doesn't allow voting, I started opening each question I flagged unsalvageable in a new tab so I could downvote them once the queue emptied.

(Some of the questions needing improvement were worthy of provisional downvotes as well, but until there's a way to see questions that were edited since downvoting, it's impractical to check up on these questions to retract votes when appropriate.  Thus I didn't vote on those questions.)

Before the triage queue, new-question triage meant looking at the new questions page, downvoting and flagging bad questions.  I should be able to do the same from the queue.

Comment: Non-dev answers are acceptable for feature-requests. Community members express their views for or against the feature-request in their answers. The status-tags which indicate the final state of the feature-request are diamond-only.