# How to review low quality answers which are not crap but just incorrect?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

When I'm reviewing "low quality posts", sometimes I'll come across an answer which has a decent explanation and sample code, it answers what's asked in the question, so it's not very low quality but I know that it is the wrong answer.

Should I mark it to be deleted since it's wrong, or mark it as "Looks OK" since it's not very low quality?

Comment: I think downvote is to discourage things; if you don't want the site to have incorrent answers you are free to downvote them.

Comment: No doubt there are some cases as described here but i just had a case an obvious repeatable bug in sql server related to spatial functions. The question was marked down twice by couple of xxx people without so much as testing what they are commenting about.
If you wish IT professionals to spend their time leaving comments and engage in your website then i suggest these kind of reviews should be outlawed or at worst there needs to be some kind of auditing of their replies.

Comment: @Farjad +1 I have seen a whole lot of incorrect answers accepted with 20+ ups.  They aren't even testing these things, when you get a +2 for accepting an answer that contributes to the problem.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If an answer is wrong it definitely needs a downvote. Even if you have to open the question in another tab to do so, please take the time to vote down incorrect information. The whole operation of Q&A requires knowledgeable people to do this to make it work. Feel free to add a comment explaining the flaw too.

As for the LQ review itself for a flawed, but otherwise decent answer "Looks OK" sounds most right to me. This is because the issue is also about an incorrectly used VLQ flag if it the only mistake is a technical one. The point of the review is to pick up on procedural, not technical flaws.

Usually the votes/comments will be enough to persuade the poster to correct/retract the answer as appropriate, which is a much better outcome than a slightly mysterious deletion.

Comment: We really ought to provide this instruction just-in-time to reviewers.  Perhaps have an option button in the "Delete" popup for "This answer is incorrect or insecure." which counts as a failed audit if selected, instead of actually casting a delete vote.  The STOP LOOK LISTEN message would then explain that wrong answers get downvoted, not deleted.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good idea. I'm seeing surprisingly many incorrectly flagged posts in the VLQ queue lately, after the UI reorganization.

Comment: Hmm... need [voting enabled in review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system) perhaps?

Comment: I know if I posted an incorrect answer, I would humbly appreciate a down vote and comment as to the flaw.  A: I'd like to know the real solution as well, since I've spent time on it (maybe as much as the OP).  B: I'd hate to be the source of bad information.

Comment: This is why I dislike the -1 when downvoting.  Its purpose is borderline practical, ie to prevent crazy downvoting, but then we have posts that should be downvoted and users find themselves hesitant to do so.  Look, institute a system where all users that downvoted get +10 if a question/answer is deleted.

Answer (score 11):

There's no delete reason 'the answer is incorrect'. So deleting would be the incorrect action.

You could even fail an audit, because many audits are highly upvoted questions which are technically invalid, because the question have reached too much attention from unexperienced users, without any expert noticing it...

Yes, there should be button 'Looks bad (but still is an answer)' or the 'Looks OK' should be renamed to 'Looks like answer', but we have to live with that.

Comment: Agree completely - there should totally be a "looks bad (but is still an answer" button - people who feel weird clicking "looks ok" when it doesn't get a better button to push that doesn't skeeve them out... then it could proceed to do completely the same thing as the other one anyway.

Comment: I would really love the 'Looks bad (but still is an answer)' ! But highly doubt such a button will ever exist ...

Comment: @neminem You may be interested in the feature request I just submitted: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278518/change-text-of-looks-ok-button-in-low-quality-queue.

Comment: I've seen a lot of answers in the VLQ queue, where reviewers are incorrectly flagging answers for deletion as "not an answer" when the answer is *indeed* an answer, just an incorrect/bad one that should instead be downvoted. This distinction should really be made clearer, perhaps by (a) allowing votes from VLQ review queue, and (b) clear instructions to downvote incorrect answers rather than delete them.

Answer (score 5):

How not to do it, and comments why not, can be very valuable to future readers of the question.  So deleting incorrect or misguided answers is not helpful.

Instead downvote and leave a comment explaining what is bad about the answer/approach.

Answer (score 3):

Leave a comment about why it's wrong, and possibly downvote the answer (although the latter might be a bit complicated if you're a reviewer, see comment below).  Site policy is to keep it though.  A public discussion about why it's incorrect could be a learning experience for the people who view the question.

Another ramification of downvotes/comments is that the person who posted the answer could come back to fix it.

Comment: Currently we are not allowed to vote directly from the review queues though. I made a [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278127/2333214) and didn't get any response, which makes me wonder whether it is encouraged.

Comment: @TJ I think we used to be able to vote from there, so maybe that was intentional?

Answer (score -16):

I think you should apply for a edit to improve the answer, first and foremost.

If your edit is refused, submit an answer yourself?

Comment: There are cases when I can't edit the answer, since it's just the wrong idea, no way to edit it to be correct. I'm not sure if I get a notification when an edit is rejected but I just move on to the next review, I don't go to the question to answer it. Maybe I should but the question as to how to review the answer still remains.

Comment: Editing the answer to correct it (unless it's a typo or similar error), would be a "radical change", and as such not allowed.