# Should we handle flags more carefully..?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I asked this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312084/2333214) here few days ago.

It was about an *Not an answer* flag declined sighting:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

Later I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8413500/2333214) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8413695/2333214) answer.

There was an issue with the data provided initially by the OP which the answer pointed out, OP replied back saying that it was a typo and he updated the question correctly in this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8413500/2).

Later an answer was posted that solved the actual issue which is accepted by the OP and is well received by the community.

So the old answer pointing to typo is now totally **obsolete**. I know a currently *obsolete* answer in certain context might help someone who is actually working on old technologies etc. But this is entirely different, it was only pointing out OP's typo and isn't going to help anyone looking for that question in future.

So is it:

- Spam? No.
- Rude or offensive? No
- Not an answer..? Was a possible answer if the issue was indeed a typo

My garbage collector is so active that I took the time to raise custom moderator flag that explained the issue: (*I hope*)

> Hi I'm flagging this because it "was" a possible answer, but the OP
>   acknowledged that it was a typo and updated the question. Now this
>   answer has no value left. It's better off deleted like an "obsolete"
>   comment

and as usual I get:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I'm [honestly trying](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278127/allow-voting-from-review-queues) to [keep SO clean](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273266/do-we-really-need-to-keep-closed-typo-questions-with-accepted-upvoted-answers).

So what is the problem here..? Is my brain wrongly collecting the garbage..?
Was the explanation poor and hard to understand (*I'm not native english speaker*) or is it some bots handling the flags nowadays..?

Comment: If it is an attempt to answer a question, the NaA flag is invalid. If it is a wrong answer, downvote it and move on. Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Comment: @TinyGiant it doesn't fall into both categories. It was an answer pointing a typo which lost it's value when OP updated question. What's the point in keeping it..?

Comment: Useless content does not warrant a flag, it warrants downvotes and possibly delete votes from users with greater than 20k rep

Comment: @TinyGiant How do I notify such users without raising a flag..?

Comment: TJ I think the point is do what you can do and what your privileges allow. But I do believe there was talk about handling obsolete posts in a new way as a new rep level privilege. Though I'm not sure where that is at. Will have to dig around

Comment: So we see trash, we confirm it is trash (downvote), and move own expecting someone responsible to collect it... Just like real world, that makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

An attempt to answer a question, no matter how incorrect it may be, is not "Not an Answer", as such the NaA flag is invalid.

**Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.**

If an answer is incorrect, you can:

- downvote,
- leave a comment letting the author know that the answer is wrong,
- vote to delete (if you have greater than 20k rep), and,
- move on.

Or any combination thereof

The deletion of such content is not your responsibility until you have 20k rep. You only need 2.3k more rep before you reach 20k, at which point you will be able to vote to delete such content.

**The flagging system is not a substitute for delete votes.**

The reason that users need 20k rep before they get to cast delete votes is because otherwise we would end up with a lot of *good* content being deleted.

As the saying goes: Don't throw the baby out with the bath water.

**Related**:

- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)
- [A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag)
- [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)