# Not an Answer flag declined while most reviewers seem to agree on Deletion

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Earlier today my 'Not an Answer' flag for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291605/2279200) was declined as "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Looking through the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10570902), it seems that the reviewers 'agree' (as I can understand it) to delete this question.

So why my flag was declined? Do I understand something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we handle flags more carefully..?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312330/should-we-handle-flags-more-carefully)

Comment: @TinyGiant, I do not think that is a duplicate. However is good 'guide' on how someone (and also myself from now on) should use the flags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I declined that flag. That was an attempt at answering the question, so a "not an answer" flag didn't apply. It wasn't a follow-on question, a "me too" comment, or "I like turtles" gibberish.

Moderators and reviewers in the Low Quality Posts queue are judging slightly different things. Our delete votes are instantaneous and binding, so we have to be careful about what we use them on. We cannot be subject matter experts on every technology covered by this site, so we use fairly simple criteria for determining when an answer should be deleted. We don't judge quality or technical correctness in answers, just whether something is obviously an answer or not.

Community votes require consensus and can be overturned easily, so reviewers can vote more freely based on quality and merit of answers, not just on whether they are answers at all. The review queue includes items flagged as "very low quality" and those that trip the quality heuristics as well as those flagged as "not an answer". Even so, [I'm sometimes concerned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers) about the frequency of delete votes in that queue.

Comment: Moderators don't have the "Skip" button in reviews?

Comment: @BhargavRao it wasn't "not an answer", why would he skip it? the flag clearly doesn't apply.

Comment: @KevinB Asking in general sense. Not in this particular case. (The flag was wrong, agree with that)

Comment: skipping doesn't really make sense as a moderator, because there aren't going to be moderators that are "subject matter experts in every technology covered by this site." If each moderator only handled topics that they *were* subject matter experts in, there would likely be a lot more unhandled flags. but i wouldn't be surprised if they did have a skip button.

Comment: Flags are presented in a generally unsorted list, not one at a time like traditional review. We pick which ones we act on from there. We defer the handling of many flags, which is a reason why you'll see some handled in seconds and some a week later. If we know a particular moderator would know more about a general subject area, we often let them handle it. The action to take on this flag seemed pretty clear to me, which is why I handled it.

Answer (score 8):

That's not a very high-quality answer, but it does attempt to answer the question. Use comments and downvotes to deal with this. I think your flag was rightly declined.

Comment: A lizard with a bow-tie and a hammer.  Who would have thunk it.

Comment: @NathanOliver You dare speak ill of my godly raiment? ;)

Comment: To tell the truth, I also down-voted and commented the answer, but I thought that it was also right to flag it. I got your point. Also @TinyGiant linked a good resource in the comments of my question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard A thousand pardons oh reptilian one.  Please do not set [your wrath](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihN3m.png) upon me. ;)