# First Posts review audit failed because of downvoting

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I was reviewing First Posts when I came across the following answer:

> This error suddenly started happening to me, like between 8am and noon
>   one day. I fixed it with the link from @tong-zhang above:
>
> [developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer](http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)
>
> I'm guessing their certificate expired, maybe?

Link to the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11292034

This answer is very short and the author only *guesses* what could be the problem and gives basically no explanation. I think it rather shouldn't be deleted, because it attempts to answer the question, and maybe even answers it correctly, but I think it's a poor answer. Therefore, I didn't flag it as VLQ or NNA, but I only tried to downvote it. It turned out that it was an audit and I saw the "Stop! Look and Listen!" message. In the moment of posting this question, the answer had 14 upvotes and no downvotes.

So my question is, is this audit a bad audit? Have I reviewed it correctly?

<sub>Note: I am asking this question because due to failing this audit, I've been banned from reviewing for 2 days.</sub>

Related:

- [Thesis: a downvote should never fail a first post audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277347/thesis-a-downvote-should-never-fail-a-first-post-audit)

Comment: If I saw this in review, I would have flagged this NAA because it's a "I had this problem too and this answer worked for me" attempt to reply to another answer (though after clicking through to the question, that other answer seems to have been deleted).

Comment: That post looks weird. The accepted answer was made yesterday, and has 354 votes. In fact, 7 answers were made yesterday. What's up with that. About the audit, I'd ask if a moderator can verify whether there was an auto low-quality flag on that.

Comment: Weird point #2: the answer seems to no longer exist, yet I can see it on the audit page. Is that normal? I don't recall being able to see deleted posts.

Comment: @Zizouz212: Yeah, some time ago audits were changed to allow deleted posts to be shown to ... everyone, I think. I believe regular reviews show deleted posts to those who reviewed them, but not necessarily others. I forget the exact details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That answer was actually reasonable - he took a *comment* on an old answer and built a new answer from it that directly solved the problem.

That said, the question was a bit of a mess; apparently something happened two days ago to make this a LOT more common, and there were probably 3-4 different answers that added little or nothing to the discussion.

I've lifted your review ban in recognition that this was a bit of a confusion scenario, but... In the future, please try to do a little bit more investigative work when there's evidently more to the story than what's shown in review (a reference to another comment or answer is a dead giveaway).

Comment: This sort of thing happens to me all the time. Just yesterday, I failed an audit because I considered an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11291374) somewhat bad, but not bad enough to be removed. So now I have to wait 6 days to continue reviewing again, and I still don't know why that question is considered bad enough to be deleted.

Comment: The short answer there is... That answer made no effort to actually answer the question, @John. It trivially *could* have - the page it links to contains the answer. But it didn't. [This is a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). In the future, try to [edit these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35149948/revisions) to provide sufficient context for the link.

Comment: I usually edit questions and answers only for linguistic errors, indentation errors and other flaws that don't involve the actual content. I rarely ever edit content, as I do not see that as a moderator's responsibility in any way whatsoever. When I believe the content is truly atrocious, I flag them and/or comment on them, but I do not believe that to be case for the answer I mentioned. IMO, it deserved a downvote at most...

Comment: @JohnSlegers but... you ain't a moderator, you are a user with [editing privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)... [use them!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575)

Comment: @Braiam : Oh, but I do use them all the time. I just focus mostly on improving the readability (language errors, code indentation, ...) and categorization (tags) of posts, rather than the actual content... which is precisely the very context described in section **When should I edit posts?** in the link you provided.

Comment: @JohnSlegers "to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / *updates as the post ages*"... you can touch the content more.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable editing a given post, you can always choose "skip" @John.

Comment: @Shog9 : I do that sometimes when I can't decide whether to to impose a sanction (closing, flagging, ...) or not. In this case, I had decided the post wasn't bad enough for any sanction to be imposed. My mistake, I guess.