# Overly Severe Review Suspension

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I recently failed an audit in the First Post review queue due to a misclick; I wanted to upvote the answer, but instead I misclicked on the down vote button.

The last audit that I failed, ***if*** my memory serves, had occurred 4 - 6 months ago.

I received a 7 day suspension on this, but I was *content* with it because
I considered it was, nonetheless, my mistake. I did not post a meta question,
as a result, because I **accepted** full responsibility for that failed audit.

But around 3 - 4 days into the suspension, I realized the suspension was changed.
It has been changed to the maximum duration allowed - one full year. I believe
it was a manual one.

For the past month, I realized that I began to review less frequently than I used to;
due to time and tiredness, I then purposefully began to skip reviewing some of the queues like LQP,
Close Votes, Suggested Edits, and have been fulfilling only 20 reviews within Triage instead of 40.

I have had about **150K** reviews altogether amongst all the queues in my history; and to have received
a one full year suspension for an automatic audit which the corresponding punishment was originally 7 days seems to 
be a bit too harsh to me (as mentioned, the last time I failed an audit had occurred around 4 - 6 months ago).

For the reasons I have expressed above, I have begun to review less frequently already; thus, my argument 
herein **focuses** on the harshness of the duration and not the fact that I ask it to be lifted because I ***must*** review.

I am not asking it to be completed lifted; the original 7 days would sound fair to me.

Comment: The First Post review queue can review ban you if you *vote incorrectly*? That seems draconian and wrong. Our up and down votes should be our own choice... and there shouldn't be a ban for simply voting up or down.

Comment: @TylerH If you get served a "known good audit" (I think it has to be 30d or older, has to have a certain score, has to have no / few downvotes, etc) then the system considers downvoting an audit failure - in the same way that the system considers upvoting a post deleted as spam / naa an audit failure.

Comment: It's vbeen known to happen that quite blatantly off topic posts get chosen as known good audits because nobody got to downvoting / closing them yet and some people upvoted.

Comment: Regarding the misclick, I have been banned once or twice for misclicking too. I don't know why the system kicks in when you **vote** instead of when you click the **I'm done** button. Even the button suggests that you are aren't done reviewing until you click it (or one of the other buttons). This really needs changing imo.

Comment: @Magisch `"in the same way that the system considers upvoting a post deleted as spam / naa an audit failure"` - except those things don't seem at all the same. You can upvote for many reasons, but generally it implies that you believe the post is belongs here (upvote and flag, delete or VTC seems illogical). You can also downvote for many reasons, many of which do **not** imply that you think the post should be closed or removed ("is not useful ... to me personally" is a valid downvote reason, so is "does not show research effort", which is not a reason to close).

Comment: hmmm here yet another reason I don't bother to help with reviews anymore - too much trouble to be worth it - Guy here is trying to help we tell him to go away for a year and then expect what?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier How about reviewing more carefully instead of not reviewing at all?

Comment: @JAL I just find the broken audits too much trouble and annoying - and looking at this audit, I'm not sure why a downvote should be a punishable offence.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier The downvote wasn't the only thing that caused the review ban here.  24 review bans were.  Misclicking the downvote button one time doesn't cause a review ban.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier You are comparing the number of review actions with the number of review bans. That is incorrect, as you need to get caught(!) on *several severely bad* actions for every ban, indicating a significant percentage of overall incorrect actions.

Comment: fair enough comment - I think I'm probably adding noise to this thread unneccesarily. Have voted and had my say.

Comment: Suspension and review ban are different things FYI

Comment: @SagarV I know suspension is manually decided by diamonds, is that review ban may be imposed automatically when failed audits reaching certain threshold?

Comment: @Tetsuya There are both automatic suspensions from reviewing (imposed after failing too many audits), and manual suspensions from reviewing handed out by diamond moderators (imposed after seeing too many wrong decisions).

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: It's not *trying* to help that helps the site. It's, y'know, *helping*. Results, not effort, are important. And anyone who exhibits a pattern of unhelpful *results* is not going to be useful to have around, making an effort to help that leads to nothing good. So yeah, audits and manual bans are driving off bad reviewers? You better believe that's by design. *Mission accomplished!* (Obviously, someone who can learn from their bans or even just audit failures and do a more reliable job is an even better success story, and that does happen too.)

Comment: According to [Andy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354563/648265), the OP isn't telling us everything.

Comment: So OP did you want an explanation or just someone to agree with you? (referring to chosen answer)

Comment: @Unheilig I was wondering why you stopped moving on the Triage Leader board.  I gave up on the First post leader board after too many suspensions.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I don't see how it is even relevant how many times this particular user has been banned. The issue here is that they claim to have been ***banned from voting incorrectly***, which if true, is just completely, shockingly wrong. Upon looking at the failed audit, we can't see what user action that was taken. (Why can't we see this? Fix it!)

First of all, we are by no means obliged to up-vote/down-vote new users when we are doing first post reviews. There is no relation between such a review and votes what-so-ever. If this is a factor when generating review audits, the audit needs to be fixed ASAP and the person who created it needs a firm kick (in their posterior or out of the building, depending on how badly this was implemented).

Naturally, no automated review audit can judge *the quality of the post*, which is the only reason for voting one way or another. If they could, then we wouldn't need user voting to begin with.

Upon considering this more carefully, I do in fact not see how the first time post queue could even have a review audit that includes a supposedly "fine" post. Because there is just no way for the audit to tell if a post is fine or not. Up-votes is no indication - the post could despite up-votes still be something like a tool recommendation or a link-only answer.

It turns even more baroque if the audit starts to require you to vote in a particular manner upon reading the post. Suppose the reviewer is a domain expert and the supposed "fine" post is actually incorrect? Or just spotting something bad with the post that an audit-generating algorithm wouldn't be capable of.

Comment: Voting down on a well received answer will fail an audit which I think is perfectly sensible (I mean, what else is it supposed to do). And the ban is just a number of failed audits (not the 1) and you know the reason for it to be extended is because there were 24 bans and/or other reviews (non audit) may have been not so great either.

Comment: "First of all, we are by no means obliged to up-vote/down-vote new users when we are doing first post reviews" nor you are obliged to say "no action needed" spam, nor edit spam, nor upvote spam, yet people does.

Comment: @EpicKip Earlier today I down-voted an answer with 30 up-votes because it was wrong and mis-quoted a language standard. It was a down vote I could confidently cast because I have extensive domain knowledge in the subject. So if such a post would pop up during review, and I spot the quality problem with it, it should then count towards my review ban? That's nonsense.

Comment: @Braiam The audit wasn't related to spam so I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: @Lundin You are suggesting that because you know 1 example all audits are bad (that's what it sounds like at least).  You need multiple failed audits for your first review ban so you wont get it from 1 bad audit. And in this case **24** review bans is too much, even if half of them were from bad audits

Comment: @EpicKip Just read my answer again...

Comment: @Lundin Stop with the noise, you read mine again. 1 bad audit won't get you a review ban period.

Comment: Well, the ban take into account more than one failed audit, so I don't see how your answer is relevant.

Comment: @EpicKip I am perfectly aware that you need to fail several audits to be review banned. That's perfectly irrelevant, thank you very much. The issue here is that someone gets punished (by the audit counting towards a ban) for voting in a way that didn't please Big Brother.

Comment: Also if it counts towards a ban or leads to a ban is completely irrelevant too, as it is just probability theory then. If someone has the bad luck to get multiple broken audits in a row, they will get banned.

Comment: @Lundin Yes but that's not the case nor has that happened before

Comment: @EpicKip This has happened multiple times and moderators have been known to manually lift bans in such cases.

Comment: I don't disagree that pass/fail audits based on voting is flawed because we are telling someone how to vote. But voting is only permitted in a small handful of queues (First Posts and Late Answers) simply because the function of those queues is to help judge the fitness of a specific question for SO, and one of the ways we do that is with Voting. So it becomes important to try to police voting in those queues to ensure people are not voting improperly by up/down voting or everything in sight. How can you do that without using audits based on perceived quality. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Magisch 1) They lift the ban, problem solved. 2) Reference

Comment: @psubsee2003 If a post is not fit for SO it should not (just) be down-voted but closed. Similarly an answer could attempt to answer the question, could be on-topic but still be of low quality. In which case it is ok to down-vote but not delete.

Comment: @Lundin agreed, but if it is fit for the site, then there's nothing to do except click "No action needed", which is a change from the current behavior since people are "encouraged" to vote in that queue.  It would be better to just removing voting from First Posts and Late Answers (looks like [Shog9 already considers this a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277347/thesis-a-downvote-should-never-fail-a-first-post-audit/277348#277348))

Comment: The op wasn't banned just for casting that vote and failing the audit. This is what the OP claimed however the answer by Andy gives the full context for why the ban was given. It was persistent bad judgement in reviewing - not decided by an automated audit system but as manually judged by humans who are highly experienced on the site. Only the 7 day ban was given for the failed audit but the OP was mistaken about the reason for the bigger ban

Comment: The reason that voting audits exist is that without them people could just hammer on the vote buttons without reading anything. We've seen this happen. When audits exist only for certain review actions, people gaming badges simply switch to the options that don't have audits and hit those buttons as quick as they can. Unfortunately, these abusive reviewers have made things a little more difficult for the rest of us. The ability [to contest borderline audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/135615) would remove most of the problems with these, but they are unfortunately necessary.

Comment: Now I agree that this particular audit failure isn't the worst, but history does matter when moderators look over reviewer behavior. Andy is actually understating things a bit, because there were 34 prior review bans here, not 24. When a reviewer hits the 20-ban threshold, they are working their way up our list of people to watch a little more closely. When someone passes 30 review bans, they're near the top of that list. It's safe to assume that very strong warnings have been issued at that point, and if troubling reviews continue we have to balance the good being done in review vs. the bad.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sWav3r7.png

Comment: @BradLarson Is there a way one can find out how many they've had? I don't remember at this point and I'm getting kinda concerned that y'all have a list :p

Comment: @Magisch - I don't think that's exposed publicly in user profiles, and moderators have to dig into private account information to get that for a specific user. However, it just was added to the moderator review ban page in order to draw our attention to ongoing problems. When people get above 20 or so bans, we tend to tell them explicitly how many they've had in pointed warnings so they know they're getting close to being banned for a year. The new [escalation of review bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296/135615) has made it harder for people to get to that level.

Comment: @BradLarson You should watch the probability that a user makes a bad review (failed audits / total review count), and not the total number of the bad reviews. Although this argument is exactly the type what I could even say to the wall.

Comment: Completely agree on this. Just because a post has 1000 upvotes and 0 downvotes does not necessarily imply that it would be wrong to downvote it.

Answer (score 113):

You failed this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16903238). You've been automatically banned due to failed audits more than two dozen times. You've had at least one manually imposed review ban for an extended length due to bad reviews of non-audit posts.

These don't seem to have caused you to slow down and review more carefully.

Regarding the harshness, I think with the number of failed audits, previous manually imposed review bans and your own words here, a longer ban from the queues is needed.

When reviewing, if you don't have time to do them carefully, you aren't helping yourself or the site. The goal of reviews isn't to have the largest number of reviews. It is to improve the quality of content on the site.

Comment: Just to add some context, while there may have been >24 automatic review bans, OP has ~78,000 reviews - coming out to one every ~3000 reviews. Considering the state of the automated audits, I don't see this as an extremely bad ratio

Comment: Yes, that was the audit that I failed, which I admitted for failing, that got me 7 days suspension but later on manually changed to 1 year. I have not had consecutive review audits that got me a 365 days suspension.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for checking. The ~78000 reviews under my review history tab are only those that didn't get deleted; if you count those from within the review queues, they should amount to almost 150K.

Comment: I disagree with the assumption that failing a review audit implies that you're doing them too fast or not carefully. 90% of the time, when I fail an audit, I had spent *extra* time analyzing that question, and ended up making the wrong decision. (more I could say but that will do)

Comment: @Rob That's a horrible comparison given that you only encounter a review audit every so many reviews (they're not a 1:1 ratio) and that a good deal of audits are blatantly obvious. Some of the worst review offenders are also the ones completing the most reviews. That many review *bans* (note that does not represent how many audits they've failed but how many times their multiple failures has resulted in a ban from review) is always bad, no matter how many reviews. You don't go around saying "well you have 100k comments, so those handful of rude ones are no big deal." They are a big deal.

Comment: @animuson Again, the initial ban was 7 days (which I accepted as mentioned in my post) but later on (after the third day or so) manually changed to 1 year. I **did not** fail consecutive and multiple reviews that led up to this duration. It was initially only for 7 days but later on changed to a year.

Comment: @Unheilig I wasn't commenting on *your* review status in particular, just in general that a low number compared to an overall total does not necessarily mean anything whatsoever.

Comment: @animuson Not sure it's fair to call it a terrible comparison. Someone with a million reviews and 2 bans is clearly doing better than someone with 100 reviews and 2 bans. It also assumes the audit system is perfect, which it's clearly not. Humans make mistakes, it's inevitable that more actions result in more mistakes. The best flaggers on the site probably have more declines flags that I, but it doesn't mean they're bad flaggers.

Comment: @Rob: review bans can't be compared to declined flags. Compare *flag bans* to review bans. Both failing a single audit and having a single flag declined from time to time is fine. But to get a review ban or a flag ban requires a *pattern of mistakes*. When you get this many review bans, then there is a *systemic failure to review properly*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Again, I did not get **automatic** banned for 365 days; it was systematically given for **7 days** but manually given for 365 days. I did not show any pattern of consecutively failing audits that led to 365 days. It was **originally** given for 7 days. A coin has two sides; could you, then, also provide a statistic for how many audits I have passed consecutively before I received this ban, which originally was 7 days, before I was manually given for 365 days in the fairest way.

Comment: @Sahuagin: failing one audit is fine. Failing enough audits to get an automatic review ban is less good, but okay if you then learn and improve your reviewing. Getting into **twenty four review bans** is **not** fine.

Comment: @Unheilig: I know what happened. A moderator reviewed your automatic review ban and decided that enough is enough and replaced that with a manual review ban.

Comment: 24 bans does seem excessive, that's a little less than one every 2 months of your SO tenure!

Comment: Flag bans don't require a pattern; [they can be triggered just by poor timing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277475/declined-in-the-last-7-days-confusingly-appears-to-list-only-flags-cast-in-the#comment898967_277475).

Comment: @JoshCaswell AFAIK that was fixed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wonder, is this a tend now? I've been review banned a couple of times before, during my "I have no clue wtf I'm doing" phase, but haven't been for a couple months or so (I think). Do I run the same risk of if I get into another review ban getting a year timeout due to this rationale?

Comment: @Magisch: you are nowhere in the same league here, I wouldn't worry. You've had 5 review bans. I see no signs that you persist on reviewing badly without learning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, aren't you guys kinda bypassing the newest implemented incremental ban system? IIRC, the ban durations now double every ban that comes less then a month after the last, and there's no cap. Is this considered not strict enough by the moderators? Wasn't the change specifically designed to adress those that get repedeatly review banned one time after the other?

Comment: @Magisch: Moderators always have had the ability to apply a manual ban, this is nothing new. The automated bans only kick in on audits, moderators are still needed to step in when we see really bad stuff making it through review. Just because someone manages to get past audits does not mean they are not making bad review decisions. If you do that consistently, of course moderators will step in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So in OPs case, they did get banned by the audit system. Did a moderator then decide that the automated system wasn't fast acting enough to keep OP out for long enough? I get manual review bans because someone made a ridiculous chain of decisions that weren't audits, but retroactively increasing ban duration on an automated ban?

Comment: @Magisch That is correct. The ban was extended

Comment: So I assume a moderator went through some backlog and found some real reviewing dirt to merit such an extension? Or was it just a case of "after 24 times they really ought to know by now"? Sorry If I'm obtuse, I'm trying to understand mod's decisions, since I assume they're meritorious

Comment: I don't suppose you have a link, @Braiam? The only FR I know of about it has no activity.

Comment: Is the point of a ban, automated or otherwise, to apply its direct effect (e.g. a 7 day ban) or to induce a behavioral change?  If it's the former, this does seem a bit jarring.  If it's the latter, is this move to keep people from accepting multiple instances of such bans as the cost of doing business and continuing the same pattern ad infinitum?  Because the review itself doesn't look especially egregious.

Comment: @bitnine It is both.

Comment: I too have been banned for 1 year from reviewing any kind of content. I see myself as improving from a person who used to post only to gain rep and badges to a person who genuinely reviewed and improved other users' posts; whether it is by simply providing a better explanation or closing the question/answer completely because it was irrelevant.

Comment: How is any of this rant even relevant? The user claims: "I wanted to upvote the answer, but instead I misclicked on the down vote button". **How could this ever be reason to ban someone???**

Comment: @Lundin That action was just the straw that broke the camels back.  Even without this there was still a ton of straw there.  You don't get review banned for a couple mistakes or a few bad audits.  You get review banned for a history of bad reviewing.  I for one think this is totally appropriate as 24 automatic suspensions indicates many audits have been failed and the user needs more of a time out to get that point across.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah so what. This is tagged discussion and what's important for meta here is not the specific case, but why there are audits present that register how you vote on posts and take actions based on it.

Comment: @Lundin I don't get your point. User is systematically not being sensible while reviewing. Who cares why the latest ban was about? The user has demonstratively being unable to pass very easy review audits. You don't get banned 24 times because you are good at reviewing nor mistakes.

Comment: So clearly there *is* a fundamental problem with the system going on here.  Something is *very* wrong that a user was able to be banned both automatically and manually *so* many times, and yet still be allowed to continue reviewing, and continue posting bad reviews.  That the person was able to make almost 80k reviews, given a demonstrated history of consistently doing a bad job of it (meaning that a high percentage of them are bad reviews) means that they've done a *lot* of damage to the site and the system has just let them keep getting back at it.  That's a major failing.

Comment: @Braiam I think Lundin's point (if I'm correct, then it's my thought, too) is that the ban should have come when OP clicked the "OK I'm Done" button, not when they clicked the downvote button. That's like getting review banned from the CV queue *as soon as you click the comment button or CV button* on a 'known good question' audit. Not even given enough time to pick a CV reason and click the actual submit button!

Comment: @TylerH which is, again, irrelevant. This wasn't the only audit they failed, there were *many others* too. OP complain that the "review suspension" was in any form severe is actively misguided, if anything, it came way too late.

Comment: @Braiam It's irrelevant to the big picture, which is that OP has a lot of audit failures. It's not irrelevant to the point of the comment that Lundin made, which is that the ban subaction is happening prematurely during the larger 'review' action. If OP had had the opportunity to fix their misclick before clicking the "I'm done" button, they would have passed the audit, and this question never would have been posted. It's unlikely a moderator would have inspected OP's account had they not been review banned again.

Comment: @TylerH yet, when we had it like that, people complained that they were wasting their time on an audit they can't do anything about anyways. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354555/overly-severe-review-suspension/354563?noredirect=1#comment501860_354664

Comment: @Braiam The point is, misclicks happen. I have failed review audits because of misclicks, though I've luckily never been banned. But I would be pissed if I misclicked on a review item and was banned *before I submitted the review*. The system *should not ban you* ***before*** you've had the opportunity to hit the "I'm Done" button. That's like saying "it doesn't matter if you failed X audits or X - 1, you should be banned", because it *does* matter. You are banned at X failed audits, not X - 1.

Comment: @Braiam It is extremely relevant if the un-vote timeout that's on all questions and answers is missing from the review queue.

Comment: @TylerH: *"this question never would have been posted"* - At 24 review bans it's pretty safe to say, that this question would have been posted at some point. Maybe not today, but if you systemically get it *this* wrong, it's an absolute necessity to ban from reviews. Not withstanding the comment made by Lundin, that an action is premature, if it *really* happens the moment you interact with any UI widget other than *"I'm done"*. I'm not sure this did happen, though.

Comment: @IInspectable Whether or not it might have been posted in the future is pure conjecture. What is known for a fact is that (assuming OP is truthful about the downvote being a misclick) the 1wk ban would not have been applied, and therefore not extended to 1 year, had OP been able to correct the misclick. At no point have I argued the ban is unjustified or that OP's review skills are above reproach or anything of the nature. Like you, I'm sure given OP's track record they would have incurred another ban soon (averaging 1 every 2 months, apparently).

Comment: @TylerH Then, if you both agree that the ban is not unjustified *and* that it would have happened at some point in the future, you should be *in favor* of automatic bans on downvoting, shouldn't you? At the very least, this precise example should give you no cause to discuss its validity.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No, because this isn't Minority Report. It could also be possible that, given the opportunity to fix the misclick and submit the review audit, OP would not make a mistake again for enough reviews/audits in a row such that he does not incur another ban *ever*. I simply think users should be allowed to complete the test before they are graded on it.

Comment: @TylerH I don't follow you. You first say "Like you, I'm sure given OP's track record they would have incurred another ban soon (averaging 1 every 2 months, apparently)." but then say the contrary, that maybe for the rest of their life they would have been flawless? I don't know, it seems that I arrive at a radically different conclusion and appreciation of the situation, given the same premises than you. 1- ban not unjustified 2- high probability of further bans 3- op has demonstrated carelessness in the past = we should be grateful that the downvote triggered the ban.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier People have been sure about things before--and turned out to be wrong. I prefer we afford people the opportunity to surprise us despite everything they've done in the past (a la US Senator John McCain and his history of 100% yes votes on repealing the US' healthcare laws - until he cast a no vote and shocked the country). The point is, even if you have a student who regularly fails quizzes, you should left them complete the quiz and go back and review their answers to be sure that's what they want to do before they turn it in, before you yank it out of their hands (1/2)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Telling them they've already marked down at least 31% incorrect answers, and therefore will fail the test. (2/2)

Answer (score 35):

I want to bring attention to [@Chris's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354555/overly-severe-review-suspension?cb=1#comment501557_354555).

> Regarding the misclick, I have been banned once or twice for misclicking too. I don't know why the system kicks in when you vote instead of when you click the I'm done button.

Being banned for a misclick is rough in my opinion. If, however, any calcuations on how you went on the audit were deferred until the reviewer clicked "I'm Done" then we know whatever they did was deliberate.

In the real world, downvotes are retractable (for a small while anyway) so I don't see why review queues should work differently.

Comment: IIRC it used to work that way. And then people got upset, because they'd spend a long time writing a helpful comment... only to find that it was an audit, and their comment would never be posted. Both the old system and the new system have their drawbacks.

Comment: @pnuts The old system: passing/failing after clicking "I'm done". The new system: passing/failing on the first action.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Hmm that is an interesting case. Goes to show you can't please everyone... I guess my counter proposal to that could be that it goes to the first action *unless* that action would result in a ban, but now we're getting overly complicated... I can see why we wouldn't want to lose a good reviewer over audits. Probably better to lose one that has an unfortunate track record...

Comment: @S.L.Barth that's interesting and a valid point. However, personally I would rather lose 10 seconds of my time than have something that I'd consider a bad UX design. One has to consider also that most comments that you'd post on someones first post would probably be something like *"Please read the [faq] and [ask]"* and not a 500-character comment.

Comment: Interesting point to bring up but it doesn't really answer OPs question. If you wanted to ask about this, you should have posted another question.

Comment: "thus, my argument herein focuses on the harshness of the duration" - @DavidG, I think this answer focuses on the harshness on the duration, or rather the ban in general, and is an attempt to gauge interest in solving it in this particular way. Would you mind elaborating on why you think otherwise? (just for my own education)

Comment: You don't mention anything to do with duration at all?

Comment: "or rather, the ban in general" - I discussed duration from a "I don't think you deserved a ban at all" perspective, ie a duration of '0'.

Comment: They've since changed it so that you find out it's an audit the moment you click on comment. Maybe first action can go and still keep that behavior so nobody writes a long comment on an audit.