# Why do review bans kick in on your first action, rather than when you submit the review?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

(Please note - I am not arguing about the outcome of the suspension post linked below; it is only relevant in that it served to shine a light on a process where I observed a potential problem).

---

The situation over at [Overly Severe Review Suspension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354555/overly-severe-review-suspension/354563) highlighted (in my opinion) a problematic work flow in the review queue. While reviewing, you are hit with random audits to ensure you are paying attention. Failing an audit is bad, and failing several can get you banned.

Okay, sounds good. However, as the aforementioned thread highlighted, the review ban will kick in *immediately* when you perform a 'wrong action' on an audit (where failing the audit would result in a ban, obviously); in this case, downvoting a 'known good post' audit immediately got the user review banned, before they even clicked "I'm Done" to submit the audit. I can only assume editing or commenting on a 'known good post' would have triggered the ban as well.

The problem here is that it was (allegedly) a misclick, and the user was not afforded the opportunity to correct that misclick before incurring the wrath of the system. We want users to learn from and correct their mistakes. So much so that when you fail an audit, you have to endure a **BIG BOLD MESSAGE** telling you that you messed up before you can proceed.

Likewise, when upvoting or downvoting a question or answer on the main site, you are afforded a length time period during which you can change your vote or simply remove it altogether. And the time frame is potentially unlimited, if the post keeps getting edited.

**So why does the system ban you prematurely here?**

The [privilege page for review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) only mentions:

> When you take one of these actions, the "I'm Done" button becomes enabled, allowing you to complete the review.

Which indicates that you complete a review when you click the "I'm Done" button. In most cases where you are tested on something, you can go back and change your answer up until you turn your test or exam in to the proctor.

The [MSE post on review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) does not mention bans or the audit process at all.

[S.L. Barth recalled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354555/overly-severe-review-suspension/354563?noredirect=1#comment501860_354664) that it used to be the other way around, but people were complaining about wasting lengthy comments on review items that turned out to be audits, so it was changed. Is that really what happened?

Comment: Why did you tag this [support] instead of [discussion]?

Comment: @CodyGray Because I want to know why a site feature works a certain way, specifically a way that seems counter intuitive to me. I'm not interested in discussing here whether the community thinks it should be changed.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not even a discussion, it's a feature request.

Comment: @Servy No, I'm not requesting that the function be changed here, either.

Comment: @TylerH The question sure doesn't read that way to me.

Comment: @Servy At what point in the question do I ask "can we please change the behavior"? I specifically and intentionally phrased this as a support question, aka "why does this feature work this way"

Comment: "Why didn't you implement this feature that I think is a good idea and instead do this other thing that I don't like instead of implementing this other feature that would be better?" is implicitly a feature request.  Yes, you didn't explicitly say, "we should implement this feature" but that's clearly what's actually going on here.  Phrasing the question as, "Why doesn't didn't you implement this feature that I want?" instead of, "We should implement this feature that I want?" isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Servy You're putting words in my mouth. It's true that I asked "why X, instead of Y" but I mention a few times in the question that Y is simply *the way I expect it to work*, not that Y is somehow better. The point of it being a support question is that I am allowing for the very real possibility that there's a *good reason* for it I haven't thought of. If there's a good reason or sound logic behind the decision, I wouldn't want it to change. Making this a feature request without first knowing the logic behind the feature would be premature.

Comment: @TylerH What a feature request *is* is a discussion over whether or not a given feature would be a good idea.  By asking whether or not a given feature that doesn't exist on the site would be a good idea, you *are* posting a feature request, because that's exactly what a feature request is.  That you're personally not convinced it's even a good idea doesn't change that.

Comment: @Servy A feature request is a request to the site operators to change a feature, and should contain sufficient logic in it to stand on its own *without* any extra discussion. That you can't accept this question means what it says and not something else is solidly your problem, not mine.

Comment: Why does a downvote end in failing an audit anyway.....? Votes are how you feel towards a question, not the consensus... A question somebody else see's as good might be seen as bad by another and vice versa.....

Comment: @Lag The audit system is very narrowly defined - My guess is that it expects *all* 'good' actions for a 'known good audit', so even a single 'bad' action makes it alarm and say "wrong action - you failed". However, there are also whole review queues where you need to review new or low quality posts, or first-time posters' content. An up or down vote there *is* part of the meat of the review in those cases. Not so much for the CV queue or suggested edit queue (which is probably why some post options like voting is hidden from certain queues).

Comment: @Lag It may become a bit more self-evident once you have access to the other 5 or 6 review queues that you can't access yet until you get to higher reputation levels.

Comment: I totally agree. At least two times I have failed due to a simple miss click.

Comment: Wait, you can get a review ban from voting down? Why?! What happened to "your votes are your own"? I thought I could do whatever I want with my votes?

Comment: @zero298: You can, unless you're reviewing. If you can't correctly identify good and bad posts according to specific criteria in the various review queues, you are welcome to use other site functionality to vote as you see fit, but you can't use /review in an entirely free-form way.

Answer (score 33):

We don't want to actually apply the action that the audit knows is wrong in the first place, so to avoid letting the post actually be upvoted/downvoted/flagged/etc. when it shouldn't be the audit fails you immediately.  The alternatives would be to either let the action happen anyway, which we just said we don't want to do, or to try to fake out the entire  UI for every single possible inappropriate action that you could take, correctly emulating everything about how it reacts, but without any lasting affects, all so that someone who did the wrong thing on an audit doesn't get a message until they click "I'm done".  That's a *lot* of work for...not really any benefit.

If you fail an audit due to a misclick, don't be too worried.  It takes a number of failed audits to actually be a problem, if you misclick once in a blue moon you'll be fine; these things happen.  If you're mis-clicking more often than that then it's probably a *good* thing if there are negative consequences, because it means that the audit is likely correct in telling you to slow down a bit and be more careful in your reviewing.

Comment: Yes, this was probably bad expressed. I meant, if it is isn't an audit, we return some information serverside. If it is an audit, why not return the same information, but not execute `SaveChanges` or whatever?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Then the UI wouldn't have the same effect as if you did the actual action in lots of situations.  There'd be tons of ways for it to go wrong.  And there's no real benefit.  Again, that's all covered in the answer.

Comment: I thought the action still occurs even if it causes you to fail the audit... at least for comments. I will have to find an audit to confirm this w/ a down/up vote.

Comment: @TylerH In most cases the action isn't possible, i.e. in the case of a known bad audit the post is deleted, and you can't vote on a deleted post, so if the audit didn't do what it did, you'd just get an error explaining that you can't vote on a deleted post.  For a known good audit, it will fail the audit when you click "add a comment" or "flag" (to open the dialog, not confirm it) not when you submit the comment/flag.

Comment: *it will fail the audit when you click "add a comment"* OMG seriously? WTF

Comment: @VladimirF It used to fail when you tried to submit the comment, but people kept complaining, so they changed it.

Comment: There are so many reasons for which one might want to comment on a post that i really, really cannot understand.

Comment: @VladimirF But those things wouldn't be what those review queues are there for.  The queues are designed to be specific and focused.

Answer (score 14):

Why should it *wait*?

Your frame of reference is fundamentally incomparable to the situation:

> ...Likewise, when upvoting or downvoting a question or answer on the main site, you are afforded a length time period during which you can change your vote or simply remove it altogether. And the time frame is potentially unlimited, if the post keeps getting edited.

Voting is not like reviewing.  Voting takes little thought and little anything else; you can vote on impulse if you really want to and the system isn't going to beat you up for it (provided you're not voting a single person's posts on impulse).  On the other hand, reviewing **demands** lots of thought and lots of patience in your judgment, and *cannot* be done on impulse.  Each action you take should be deliberate and methodical.

I don't deny people make mistakes, but the sooner those mistakes are identified, the sooner they can remedy them.  It doesn't make much sense to me to *wait* for them to take the terminal action if we know what they did was wrong *right away*.  This way, the feedback loop is shortened; they know they made a mistake and they know what they did to cause that mistake.

I won't go into the specifics of the case you're highlighting, but I would imagine that if a user doesn't get the hint after X number of tries, then a longer ban is *more* than justified.

Comment: That's a fair point - the review queue is not a drive-by system like Q&A, and actions there have heavier consequences than actions taken from the Q&A page in general; you go there deliberately and make intentioned *reviews* of site actions, so it would expect a higher threshold of accuracy, at every point in the process.

Comment: Why shouldn't the system wait till the reviewer clicks done? Your answer, in my opinion, does not address the possibility of a mis-click. <<It doesn't make much sense to me to wait for them to take the terminal action if we know what they did was wrong right away.>> This *right away* can be at least after the reviewer is "done" with the task.

P.S. @Servy's answer (which I read afterwards) makes some sense on why the system shouldn't account for mis-clicks.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: Misclicks are a side effect of inaccurate and indeliberate actions.  I have a muscle spasm which does impact my right hand; on occasion I click with it.  This is why I don't bother with the mouse until I know I'm done reviewing everything I can.  Accidents happen, but be more than prepared to own up to them.

Comment: I do a lot of reviewing on a tablet / phone and fat finger effect happens there a lot more than when I use a laptop or desktop. I have been lucky so far and none of the fat-finger incidents involved audits. I would be quite furious if I failed an audit just because this. @Servy's answer makes more sense explaining the technical difficulties behind this.