# I didn't pass when I downvoted a deleted answer that had negative score?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-answers

The review https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30295664

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801763/6699433

> In Nextjs 12 , it can be implemented using _middleware.[js/ts] file in your API folder.
>
> Below example repository can help : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-middleware

The answer is deleted and downvoted. It has no upvotes. How could it not be correct to downvote it?

Or was the problem that I didn't do enough? I downvoted and clicked "other action". Was the problem that I didn't ALSO flag it or vote to delete?

I found this answer when I searched for what to flag:

> What NOT To Flag
>
> Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
>
> You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are still answers, so you should not flag them.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/6699433

But sure, that is about NAA-flags. I guess I could have flagged this as VLQ. But am I really required to do that on top of downvoting? Would I also have failed if I only flagged it but did not downvote?

EDIT:

The message I recieved was requested in comments. Here it is:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

Comment: Probably because the review is expecting you to vote to delete as a "link only answer."

Comment: @Larnu Sounds weird. That would imply auto-fail if I don't have any delete votes left. :D

Comment: @Larnu Besides, It's pretty common to just leave a comment on those, saying something like *"It would be good if you provided more information from the link, in case the link rots"*

Comment: What was the message associated with the audit failure? I'm not hugely familiar with this queue but I'm confused that such a failure is possible. I thought that when a post was bad, _any_ kind of action consistent or potentially consistent with the post being bad (i.e. close vote, downvote, VLQ vote, comment, or edit) was supposed to pass the audit.

Comment: @MarkAmery: As I understood it, they downvoted, and then selected "Other action" and submitted. I also don't know for sure which action would have counted as success, but I guess it's either just picking "Leave feedback", or flagging and "Other action".

Comment: It's a bug and staff is aware: [Unable to pass First Question / First Answer review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371701/295232)

Comment: Since it appears there's a bug in play here, I'll lift the suspension. Just be aware, the two other audits you failed to get suspended were indeed incorrectly reviewed.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks. And yes, I'm perfectly aware that those two were correct.

Comment: Comments cleaned up. If you want to discuss the finer points of this review queue, please post a new Meta question for that.

Comment: @TechInquisitor As is clear from the [linked post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371701/271271), this was originally reported 6 hours prior to you leaving your comment. It's not reasonable to be upset or indignant that it hasn't been fixed in that amount of time. Everyone that's working at SE is human. Fixing things takes time. Yeah, sure, there's a *lot* of stuff which SE allows to languish unfixed, and I'm certainly frustrated about a good amount of it, but let's be reasonable about something that was only *very* recently reported.

Comment: First answer review audits are simply broken by design. I pointed this out [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354698/584518) many years ago but it wasn't very popular for some reason. They remain broken to this day.

Comment: Overall, the review audits have always been broken and will never get fixed. The solution from a user's perspective is to _boycott review work_ so that SO either has to fix the reviews or let paid staff do them instead.

Answer (score 9):

This should be fixed now. Audits broke on November 8 on the First Question and First Answer queues when a deliberate switch fall-through in the typescript ... un-fell-through?... and a critical part of the audit code was no longer being correctly referenced. I fixed this in December and fully forgot to also update Meta about it, my apologies. You should now be able to pass audits in the correct scenarios. Please let me know if you're still experiencing this issue, and thanks for the report!

Answer (score 2):

Link only answers should at least be flagged as very low quality. You can't run out of those, so there shouldn't be any blocking problem.

You may leave a comment in addition to flagging or downvote the answer, but not flagging is definitely wrong. If you only comment or vote, who is going to check if the author ever reacts to your comment?

Regarding flagging as VLQ (or NAA for that purpose): Yes, "Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer!". Except when it's only pointing to some other site which answers the question, then its link-only and should be flagged. I can't judge if

> In Nextjs 12 , it can be implemented using _middleware.[js/ts] file in your API folder.

is enough information to stand as an answer (without following the link), but at least some people in the LQP queue decided that it isn't and deleted the answer based on that.

The audit system is designed to assume that previous actions were correct. If they aren't, then the audit system will fail. But that's then not a problem of the First Posts queue but of fixing the original mistake.

Comment: Sure, but according to other posts, this is not a link only answer. At least not the way it should be to flag it. This answer is an answer. Without the link it's not much, but it's *something*.

Comment: Citing from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/6699433) *" **What NOT to flag** Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers. You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are still answers, so you should not flag them."*

Comment: @klutt: Is the text of the answer without the link enough to solve the problem in question? I can't tell because it's not my area of expertise. The answer has been deleted as being link only. If you disagree with this, then it's not a problem of how posts are handled in the First posts queue, but rather a problem of a wrong decision in some other queue.

Comment: @klutt: The audit system assumes that the previous action was correct. Based on that it decides which actions are appropriate. On the other hand: If the post is not link only and contains enough information to solve the question, then why even downvote or leave a comment?

Comment: Do you have any citation or something that gives clear instructions about this? I was completely convinced that if an answer is considered "bad", then you can choose freely between flagging, down vote and delete vote as long as you don't click that it's ok as it is or upvote it.

Comment: I have now gotten my review ban lifted because this was caused by a bug. So it seems like this answer is wrong.

Comment: *You can't run out of those* yes you can (unless you are a moderator). The maximum per day depends on reputation and # of helpful flags and caps at 100.

Comment: @klutt perhaps you shouldn't have failed the audit because of the choice to quality vote but that doesn't imply the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Gimby The question is why I failed the audit