# First Answer "The answer must be flagged first to select this option" for other action enabled on downvote. Bug?

Tags: support, review-queues, first-answers

I decided to refreshed my memory by going to [First Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) help.

I noticed under **Other action** it indicates:

> Choose **Other action** if the post needs to be flagged or requires a combination of interactions. **The answer must be [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) first to select this option**.

If someone downvotes the post, it opens up this option.

Unless I'm misreading, these two are **mutually exclusive**. Only one is correct. Which one?

- Opening up "Other Action" on a downvote allows the option to be chosen.
- The help is correct, you should avoid "Other Action" and also flag the post.

I'm aware of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412941), but it indicates fixed on 11/8/21.

Comment: I'm convinced the entire system is broken. You can indicate that a post deserves the harshest penalties possible (by flagging as spam and downvoting, for example) but the "Looks OK" button is still available.

Answer (score 6):

A vote (both up or down) makes "Other action" selectable. In fact, editing (by clicking "Edit" under the post), flagging and commenting (by clicking "Add a comment") also activate "Other action". Doing any of these and choosing "Other action" records your review as "Reviewed" in your review history. You can verify all of these on the [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/).

I think the help center is simply incomplete on this. It should say "The answer must be **acted on** first to select this option."

Comment: By your response, then the documentation is wrong? When it says you must flag to choose other?